# Disable mfSideMenu when swipe right

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have implemented `MFSideMenu` in my project. It works great but only problem is it gets opened up when I swipe right on the screen. Need to disable it.

I have to implement swipe gestures for pushing and popping controllers.

```
navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewCtrl];

navigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:72.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1];
SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
container.panMode = 0;
container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
             containerWithCenterViewController:navigation
             leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
             rightMenuViewController:nil];


self.window.rootViewController=container;
```

Comment: ok I assign some new code

Comment: Ok thanks  @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this line in viewWillAppear solves this issue

```
[self.menuContainerViewController setPanMode:MFSideMenuPanModeNone];
```

Comment: @anbu.Karthik - Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use this its working for me:

```
SideMenuViewController *leftSideMenuController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [self navigationController];
UINavigationController *leftnavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftSideMenuController];
if (!sideMenu)
{
    sideMenu = [MFSideMenu menuWithNavigationController:navigationController
                                 leftSideMenuController:leftnavigationController
                                rightSideMenuController:nil];
}
sideMenu.menuSlideAnimationEnabled = NO;
leftSideMenuController.sideMenu = sideMenu;
sideMenu.panMode=MFSideMenuPanModeNavigationController;
return sideMenu;
```